# Strategies for Diagnosing Memory Leak in C# program updating an Azure Table

Tags: c#, azure, memory, memory-leaks, azure-storage

I have a fairly simple application that takes a data file with about 500k lines of data in it, parses the data, organizes it and then inserts it into an Azure Table. There are about 2000 of these files and I need the process to work smoothly as I load all of the data.

I am using WindowsAzure.Storage v5.0.2 for inserting the data and Microsoft.tpl.dataflow v4.4.24 for parallelization. Each file is completely processed and all tasks finalized before I move onto the next file. I am also disposing of all objects I can and setting everything else to Null at the end of each file load.

Despite trying to be as careful as possible the RAM usage goes up steadily until it crashes the process. When it starts it jumps up to 1 GB of RAM used and steadily climbs until the process crashes somewhere above 9GB of RAM consumed.
Note - this is targeting x64 on a reasonably large computer. Garbage collection is happening on a regular basis, but it doesn't seem to affect the memory problem.

At this point I am completely confused about where the memory leak is coming from and don't have any idea about how to diagnose the problem.

**Update**

After a lot of work and following the suggestion below I found out that the parallelization I was using was allowing more simultaneous insert processes than I expected. It looked like the insert was complete and my code was starting the next insert. In reality the parallel process had just reported back a status but had not finished. This led to a huge backlog of simultaneous inserts happening, chewing up RAM and crashing the system. It also cause me to go past my IOPS limit which I believe triggered throttling, compounding the problem.

Figuring this out required a huge amount of work and many different ways of analysing everything, but the suggestion below got me going in the right direction.

Comment: There's `MergeOption.NoTracking` which maybe has to deal with how Azure Tables client consumes memory.

Comment: this application is focused on loading data into the table so .NoTracking doesn't affect anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a search for 'troubleshoot .net memory leak' will yield lots of results, but probably the best one is http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2009/05/12/debug-diag-script-for-troubleshooting-net-2-0-memory-leaks.aspx.

Basically, use DebugDiag to generate a memory leak analysis report and then look for which objects are consuming all of the memory.  You will likely see one type of object that you didn't realize you were continuously adding to a collection without removing it later on.

Comment: A little late for my response, but I checked you as my answer. This suggestion did lead me to the solution.